# Why is Bootstrap (3) not displaying correctly in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to update the look of the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) sign in page using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I'm using a [gem](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) by anjlab for Bootstrap 3.

I'm running Rails 4.0 and I'm attempting to replicate the example found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/):

[image]

but when I copy the html I get the following in my application:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if I've not configured something correctly. Can someone assist to so I can get my sign in page looking like the example on the bootstrap website?

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Manager</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/volunteers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/home.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/volunteers.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="0N/QEWp3XUuCrFUPqKQ4VDyy6ALfum9TwFoZDg8f2r0=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus="">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

#Bootstrap 3
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', '~> 3.0.0.3', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.0.1'


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

This is my application.css.scss file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

And my custom.css.scss file:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Can you post markup/css? It's difficult to diagnose this issue otherwise.

Comment: Shoot.. I knew I forgot something! Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot another style : [signin.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css)

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```